# French translation of DRY (Don't repeat yourself)

Tags: traduction, informatique

In software engineering, [don't repeat yourself](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ne_vous_r%C3%A9p%C3%A9tez_pas) (DRY) is a principle of software development aimed at reducing repetitions of all kinds.

How would you translate the acronym in French?

I've come up with "**Sans erreurs copiées-collées**" for "SEC" but there is no "mistakes" involved in English. We could also use something for "ARIDE" like "**Abstinence répétitive indicative d’excellence...**", but it's pretty heavy.

Any ideas?

Comment: ELR : *évitez les répétitions* ? It lacks the mnemotechnic part of course, but your propositions seem unusable to me...

Comment: Eureka ! SEC : *sobre et concis* Like it ?

Comment: DRY code has led to WET (Write Every Time) code... an extended pun.

Comment: @RomainValeri i will use this one until something better come up, thanks =)

Comment: @HydrangéacéeslesHydrangelles Dans le monde du développement, il y a peu de chance qu'on fasse l'amalgame avec l'autre extension de SEC. Pour le reste, il ne me vient pas de mots comme ça, mais il est vrai qu'on utilise toujours des mots/expressions en anglais, donc ce n'est pas forcément gênant. Après, il peut y avoir des p'tites phrases amusantes qui font slogan : "Compiler, c'est livrer", "Tester, c'est douter", même si elles sont plus satiriques, tu peux peut-être en trouver une pour le copier/coller de code.

Comment: @Larme Merci. C'est qu'en plus bien avec _dry_ on devine que _y_ en fin de phase c'est le pronom réfléchi, qui va commander un verbe en début de phrase et la forme négative plus usuelle pour dire quoi _éviter_ et l'acronyme court esquisse donc une locution verbale. Mais le copier-coller n'a rien à voir avec l'économie (économe), ou la duplication, c'est de l'inattention quand on pense qu'un truc peut marcher tel sans modif. Économie, prudence, clarté, logique, inocuité, sécurité, intégrité, compatibilité, prévisibilité évoquent à mon avis bien davantage que ces charades mnémotechniques en Fr.

Comment: @Larme Enfin je perçois dans la non duplication un appel soit à une plus grande abstraction soit à une stylistique plus élégante en développement. Je ne sais pas combien d'acronymes il faudra pour nous dire toutes les situations où on serait interpellé par ce genre de logique. C'est bien intéressant mais je ne suis pas un développeur. Merci.

Comment: @Laure An extended as well as an intended pun, I presume.

Answer (score 3):

To translate the repetition, i would use a more suitable word in french : *redondance* (which is also used in the french translation of the wikipedia section for DRY), with a simple accronym :

HARI (Halte Aux Redondances Inutiles).

Comment: Et en rajoutant un mot en D derrière pour faire HARID ? : "Halte au redondance inutiles, Danièle|développeur|démon."

Answer (score 0):

You just don't. Maybe our québecois have something to replace it ?

French people in IT do not know their own language anymore. I've fought for months to use "démobiliser" instead of "decommission" but nobody ever understood me. So I also switched to English "commission", but then again, nobody understood it.

Answer (score 0):

The literal translation would be "[ne vous répétez pas](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ne_vous_r%C3%A9p%C3%A9tez_pas)", but NVRP has not the same effect as DRY.

As Benoît mentioned, IT folks would use the acronym as an "anglicisme".